# Recursion fails on specific server

Tags: php, recursion

There is usual recursive function. It iterates twice - first main iteration and second inner iteration:

```
function recursive() {
    global $a, $stop;

    $stop++;

    foreach($a as $val) {
        echo $val;
        if ( $stop < 2 )
            recursive();
    }
}

$a = array(1,2);
$stop = 0;
recursive();
```

The result is `1122`. Everything is right. Second iteration is within first: `1(12)2`

I changed my server and new server echos `112`. First loop stops after Second iteration: `1(12)`.
It always stops. Only one iteration is possible, and then it is done.

What is wrong with this server? Is it any php's option or what?

Comment: You're using the same name for parameter `$a` and global `$a`, which is suspicious enough that the behavior might be different in different versions of PHP. Although now you edited the code -- are you sure this is exactly the code you have?

Comment: Why are you using global $a if you passed it into the function?

Comment: @Truth I wonder the same thing...

Comment: @Truth it seems the OP just made a ninja edit :-P (still do not understand why the OP is using gloabls however...)

Comment: You are too fast, I edited it as soon as I posted it )

Comment: So *this exact code* which is in your question acts as you say it does on the server, or is this a simplification of what you actually have?

Comment: @Juhana, this code works ok one one sever. But not ok on other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using static values instead of the globals (which are useless in your case):

```
function recursive($a) {
    static $stop = 0;

    $stop++;
    foreach($a as $val) {
        echo $val;
        if ( $stop < 2 )
            recursive($a);
    }
}

$a = array(1,2);
recursive($a);
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/rP7HVKXx

Comment: Seems too work on both sides. So, it is php-version specific. globals works somewhere. But not everywhere.

Comment: @Qiao what is your reasoning for using globals?